# Second JOptionPane goes to behind all programs

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

In my Java Agent if I put two JOptionPane,one after other, the second one goes to behind all my applications opened.

I already tried

- Change `null` for `this`; 
           But I get this:

  ```
  The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object, String, int) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (JavaAgent, String, String, int)"
  ```
- Get all Parent Component possible.
           But also didn't work
- Set `setAlwaysOnTop` permission in my java.policy file,also didn't work
- My class already extends another class that I need, so i can't extend `javax.swing.JDialog`.

The code that I use is:

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase{

private static int erros=0;
private static int count=0;

public int getErros(){return erros;}
public int getCount(){return count;}

public void NotesMain() {
    System.out.println("\n\nStart of Agente!");

    try {

        Session session = getSession();

        Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
        View vw = db.getView("vwTodas");

        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        //Get the file by file chooser

            /* Filter FileReader through a Buffered read to read a line at a
            time */
            BufferedReader bufRead = null;

            try{
                //read the file         
                //work in the file
                }

            }catch(IOException a){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problems reading the file!","Problems!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }finally{
                try{
                    bufRead.close();
                }catch(IOException b){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problems closing the file!", "Problems!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\n\nEnd of Agente!");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Documents sent: " + count + "\nErrors during the import: " + erros +   "\nTotal: " + (count+erros),"Erro",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }       

    } catch(NotesException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Any idea?

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Comment: Also, you are passing a `null` into the JOptionPane's first parameter, and shouldn't be doing that. Instead pass a reference to the current parent window or one of its components, the window that generates the JOptionPane.

Comment: I can't get this references, i tried, but i failed :(
I tried get the first and the most high level father window or one of its components references.

Comment: I edited the post with the code, if you need more, please let me know

Comment: Thank you. What is View? What is `frame`? Where is your GUI in all of this? And does a GUI call this code? Also consider creating and posting a [mcve].

Comment: Hello there! This code is from an agent that runs in Lotus Notes from IBM. So the GUI question is not that easy to answer, I have a Page with a button that calls this agent when clicked. View it's a way to see Documents save from Formularies. I have read this link, but this code is the most verifiable exemple that I can send.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `JFrame`, set it to always on top and pass that `JFrame` in as the parent component of your `JOptionPane`:

```
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();
parentFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problems closing the file!", "Problem!",      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Alternatively, if you have a parent component already available, then you should use that as your `JOptionPane`'s parent component

Answer (score 1):

You state:

> Change "null" for "this"; But I get this: "The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object, String, int) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (JavaAgent, String, String, int)"

The error message is explaining exactly what's wrong -- the class that represents `this`, JavaAgent, does not derive from java.awt.Component, and the solution is to fix this -- to place in a parameter that *does* derive from java.awt.Component. Period. That's it.

How to do this specifically will all depend on code that you're not showing us. So yes, my answer is incomplete, but someone else has already posted what I consider to be a misleading answer, and so I felt that I had to post something. Please improve your question so that I can improve this answer.

Comment: Just wondering what you thought may be misleading about my answer so I can improve it (and maybe improve my understanding also)